# Foreach loop in Powershell via XML

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

Below is my XML

```
<step>
    <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
    <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
    <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
</step>
<step>
    <filename>NX1872_01\tools\checkReg.ps1</filename>
    <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
    <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
</step>
<step>
    <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
    <lookfor>Y:\\CATIAcfgV5</lookfor>
    <replace>C:\BM\CATIAcfgV5</replace>
</step>
```

I am trying to refer above XML to replace the strings in files that are mentioned in **filename** node.

Eg: I took reference from the XML for filename & its path like(tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat) then I look for **"W:\ugs"** & replace with **"C:\BM\ugs"**. This is the first step for foreach loop but if you see the 3rd step which has the same file name, but I am looking for a different string but foreach loop didn't do the replacement for the second occurrence which have the same file name.

Below is my code which I am using in Powershell

```
$testXML = C:\test\settings.xml
[xml]$SpecialXMLFile = Get-Content $testXML
foreach ($step in $SpecialXMLFile.step)
{
    $_aux = C:\temp
    $_aux_dest = D:\temp
    $srcfilename = $_aux + "\" + $step.filename
    $destfilename = $_aux_dest + "\" + $step.filename
    $strun = Get-Content $srcfilename
    $strun -replace $step.lookfor, $step.change | Out-File -Encoding ascii $destfilename
}
```

Could you please let me know where I am doing wrong or I need to add some more steps?

Comment: $SpecialXMLFile.configuration.replace.step should be $SpecialXMLFile.configuration.step.replace no?

Comment: Your posted  XML does not match the path you state in your code. It's missing [configuration], and you have items in your code that do not clarify what there are or are there for, Lastly, you are really over-engineering this use case. XML/JSON is native to PowerShell and it has cmdlets to work with them.

Comment: @Esperento57 yes sorry I have another two nodes before the step nodes where I forget to mention

Comment: @postanote I am using XML file becouse I don't want to change code each & every time I just do the changes in XML to modify my code & accordingly it will do the changes in config files.

Comment: So, are you saying that you never know what is in the XML file? You can just set your code to read the XML you receive and prompt for what node/value you want to work with. In the sample I provided, it just grabs the main configuration node and displays the step node to work with. You then use those params to do as you wish. YOu can prompt for any of that. No change in base code needed.

Comment: Please, for clarity, edit your question and show us the desired output. To me, it is very unclear what is is you want replaced in the file.

Comment: @Theo I have edited my question please go through it & let me know if you need any more clarification on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment.

```
Get-Command -Name '*xml*'
# Results
<#
CommandType Name          Version Source
----------- ----          ------- ------
Cmdlet      ConvertTo-Xml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Export-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Import-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Select-Xml    3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Select-Xml).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Select-Xml).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Examples
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Full
Get-help -Name Select-Xml -Online
```

Thus, why not use the native Select-Xml cmdlet to cheery pick the node you want and modify as needed.

Example get the step values:

```
(@'
<configuration>
    <step>
        <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
        <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
    </step>
    <step>
        <filename>NX1872_01\tools\checkReg.ps1</filename>
        <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
    </step>
    <step>
        <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
        <lookfor>Y:\\CATIAcfgV5</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\CATIAcfgV5</replace>
    </step>
</configuration>
'@  | 
Select-Xml -XPath '//configuration').Node.step
# Results
<#
filename                                          lookfor        replace         
--------                                          -------        -------         
tk1872_01\data\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat        W:\\ugs        C:\BM\ugs       
NX1872_01\tools\checkReg.ps1                      W:\\ugs        C:\BM\ugs       
tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat Y:\\CATIAcfgV5 C:\BM\CATIAcfgV5
#>
```

Then replace with whatever, using what is given.

Comment: No worries, it happens. It just makes us have to assume/guess at what is really going on, though that makes responding a challenge. For example, the first two lines in your code are redundant, unless you are prompting for that file name. $_aux* is not defined anywhere in your code, so, what's in it is a mystery and $step.change, has no reference in the XML. So, show more of your XML, code definition, and expected result.

Comment: @postnote 

as I said I am sorry I have provided short information. I have edited my question again with the correct information as you requested. I think I failed to keep you understand what I wanted to. my real concern is when I loop through a step in Powershell in the output file it only changes the first occurrence which is 
`<lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor><replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace></step>`
not another one which is 
`<lookfor>Y:\\CATIAcfgV5</lookfor><replace>C:\BM\CATIAcfgV5</replace>`

Comment: I mean to say is if the filename occurs two times it's only considered the first occurrence, not the second one. it is not replacing the string a second time when the same filename is there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining further.

The XML you are showing misses a root element, so I have used this:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<root>
    <step>
        <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
        <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
    </step>
    <step>
        <filename>NX1872_01\tools\checkReg.ps1</filename>
        <lookfor>W:\\ugs</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\ugs</replace>
    </step>
    <step>
        <filename>tk1872_01\data\nx1872\nx1872_base_include_wrn.dat</filename>
        <lookfor>Y:\\CATIAcfgV5</lookfor>
        <replace>C:\BM\CATIAcfgV5</replace>
    </step>
</root>
"@
```

In real life, you would want to read this from a file using

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'C:\test\settings.xml' -Raw
```

The thing is, that in various steps the same file needs to be adjusted and in your code that does not happen because the file is read in twice to only replace one `lookfor` value. The second time around, the same (unchanged) source file is read in and again only one replacement is done.

What you need to do is to group the steps where the filename is the same, get the content from that file only once and do all replacements needed on it. Then output to a new file in the destination path.

```
$sourcePath  = 'C:\temp'
$destination = 'D:\temp'
# combine the steps where the filenames are equal
# if your xml has a different named root, change that here
$xml.root.step | Group-Object filename | ForEach-Object {
    # create the paths from the groups name
    $fileIn  = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $_.Name
    $fileOut = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
    # test if the output directory path for the file exists. If not create it first
    $pathOut = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($fileOut)
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $pathOut -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $pathOut -ItemType Directory
    }
    # read the input file as a single multiline string
    $content = Get-Content -Path $fileIn -Raw
    foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        # replace as many times as needed
        $content = $content -replace $item.lookfor, $item.replace
    }
    # are you sure about the -Encoding ascii ??
    $content | Out-File -FilePath $fileOut -Encoding ascii
}
```